# Error when building tensorflow 2.3.1 for raspberry pi 4

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build tensorflow 2.3.1 following the guide here -

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi#python-3.7

It runs for a while (more than an hour) and then fails trying to find python2.7 arm libs.
Error message is as shown below -

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from bazel-out/armeabi-opt/bin/external/pybind11/_virtual_includes/pybind11/pybind11/detail/common.h:112,
                 from bazel-out/armeabi-opt/bin/external/pybind11/_virtual_includes/pybind11/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                 from bazel-out/armeabi-opt/bin/external/pybind11/_virtual_includes/pybind11/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                 from bazel-out/armeabi-opt/bin/external/pybind11/_virtual_includes/pybind11/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                 from bazel-out/armeabi-opt/bin/external/pybind11/_virtual_includes/pybind11/pybind11/pybind11.h:44,
                 from tensorflow/python/profiler/internal/profiler_wrapper.cc:19:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:24:54: fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7/pyconfig.h>
                                                      ^
compilation terminated.
INFO: Elapsed time: 18.525s, Critical Path: 1.26s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

If I modify Dockerfile to include python2.7 arm library the build passes but it generates `.whl` for python2.7 instead python3.7.

Am I missing something or is this a bug with the build steps documented?

Comment: I'm getting the same error building Tensorflow 2.4.0 for Python 3.8 (tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON38 tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh).